# Do coupled angular momentum eigenstates depend on angle between particle positions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

Suppose we have two particles with positions $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$. The corresponding coupled angular momentum eigenstates would be expressed via Clebsch-Gordan coefficients as (according to [this link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-73-introductory-quantum-mechanics-i-fall-2005/lecture-notes/sec8.pdf))

$$|j,m,j_1,j_2\rangle=\sum_{m_1=-j_1}^{j_1}\sum_{m_2=-j_2}^{j_2}|j_1,m_1,j_2,m_2\rangle\langle j_1,m_1,j_2,m_2|j,m,j_1,m_1\rangle\tag1$$

Now the uncoupled eigenstates are

$$\langle \vec r_1,\vec r_2|j_1,m_1,j_2,m_2\rangle=Y_l^m(\vec r_1)Y_l^m(\vec r_2).\tag2$$

Now I introduce three Euler angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and an interparticle angle $\xi$, defined by

$$\cos\xi=\frac{\vec r_1\cdot\vec r_2}{\sqrt{\vec r_1^2\vec r_2^2}},\tag3$$

and express the cartesian coordinates of the system using rotation matrices: $R_z(\alpha)$ for rotation around $z$ and $R_y(\alpha)$ for rotation around $y$. Then I have:

$$\vec r_1=R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\gamma)\begin{pmatrix}\cos\xi\\ \sin\xi\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\tag4$$
$$\vec r_2=R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\gamma)\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.\tag5$$

This follows the "zyz" definition of Euler angles. Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ seem to agree with $(3)$.

Now I plot dependence of coupled eigenstates $(1)$ on $\xi$, expecting to see only change by a global phase factor in this dependence when changing Euler angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. But what I get is unexpected. Although indeed $\alpha$ only seems shift global phase, changing $\beta$ or $\gamma$ appears to change the shape of magnitude of this dependence. This is apparent e.g. for $|j,m,j_1,j_2\rangle=|2,1,1,1\rangle$.

So I wonder: is it what I should get, or have I made a mistake somewhere? If it's what I should get, then why is there a nontrivial dependence of coupled angular momentum eigenstates on variable, which is not related to orientation of the system?

Comment: Your question lacks details: which meaning have the vectors r_1 and r_2, which origin of axes did you choose? Cannot this origin be taken at the location of one of the particles? Or, alternatively, are these particles electrons of one and the same atom? And if not, are the particles polarized, i.e. with definite projections on some particular axes?

Comment: @Sofia the vectors are position vectors in an inertial reference frame. I thought the default reference frame for physics problems is an inertial one. Thus we can't take the origin at the location of one of the particles. And I don't consider some specific state of the particles - just an eigenstate of these two particles in spherically symmetric potential.

Comment: But, these two particles aren't quantum particles? And if they are, don't they gravitate around the center of the spherically symmetrical potential? Next, if the answer is positive why don't you use the simple spherical coordinates r, θ, φ ? What you exactly want to do with those Euler angle? Do you try to see what does to the coupling a rotation of axes?

Comment: Yes, they are quantum. And they can gravitate around the center of spherically symmetrical potential, but they don't have to. The potential may be free space, so that radial wavefunctions would be spherical Bessel functions, which represent free solutions. If I use spherical coordinates for each particle, it'll be good enough in uncoupled case, but in general in coupled case the angular momenta of each particle don't conserve, thus spherical coordinates become bad choice of coordinates. Euler angles give the orientation of _the system_, which is what characterized by total angular momentum.

Comment: I apologize, I left you three days ago. Can you tell me what means for you the angle ξ ? Quantum particles are not localized, unless their wave-functions are δ-Dirac. I see that you describe r_2 in some frame of coordinates with some origin) as (1, 0, 0), and r_1 as (cosξ, sinξ, 0). But, since these positions are in general undefined, so is the angle between their vectors.

Comment: These coordinates represent the states with definite positions. Of course, such states are described by Dirac deltas. You have to introduce some position-related basis if you want to talk about QM with any relation to position-detecting experiment. In the same way one-dimensional wavefunction $\psi(x)$ depends on $x$ coordinate, in which the particle isn't localized in its eigenstate, but $|x\rangle$ is nonetheless a very useful basis.

Comment: Of course, Ruslan, that you need a system of POSITION coordinates, s.t. the particle 1 will be described by (x_1, y_1, z_1) or in spherical coordinates by (r_1, θ_1, φ_1) while the particle 2 will be described by (x_2, y_2, z_2) or by (r_2, θ_2, φ_2). But nobody promises us that the angle between our particles will stay constant during their movement, or that is has a MEANING at all. I mean, you can describe the 2nd particle by the coordinates (r - r_1, θ - θ_1, φ - φ_1) but all these three differences are not constant. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not talking about the _angle_ being constant. I'm talking about the dependence of the state function $\langle r_1,r_2,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\xi|j,m,j_1,j_2\rangle$ on angle $\xi$. I'd suppose it should be more or less constant - i.e. constant up to global phase. And my question is concerning why it's not, because the total momentum eigenstate is supposed to depend only on orientation of the system not on its internal state. BTW, you'd better use $\LaTeX$ instead of hand-picking greek letters, see [help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: No, Ruslan, I don't have patience for LATEX, or any learning now, I have things on my head. But, let me put a SMALLER problem: assume that j_1 = j_2 = constant (you pick the value), and only m_1 can take different values, and so m_2. too. Also, let the axis Y remain in its place and rotate only X and Z. So, we will have α = γ = 0, and only β is needed. And of course the angle ξ that interests you. WHERE do you introduce the rotation by β ? In the CG coefficients (do you have the formulas for transformation at a rotation of axes)? In the azimuthal functions exp(i m_1 φ_1) and exp(i m_2 φ_2)?

Comment: (continuation) I think that here enters the angle ξ that interests you, i.e. φ_2 = φ_1 + ξ .

Comment: The rotation by $\beta$ will be in the coupled functions $\exp(im_{\xi}\xi)\exp(im_{\beta}\beta)$, which will result from uncoupled $\exp(im_1\phi_1)\exp(im_2\phi_2)$. Yes, the angle $\xi$ will be the difference of $\phi_i$'s while $\beta$ will be a (half) sum. In the case of such 2-dimensional coupling though there's no strangeness: change of $\xi$ only changes the global phase, unlike the case of full 3-dimensional coupling.